# How to extend Equatable to a class which has extend and mixin with already?

Tags: flutter, dart, state, mixins

How can I extend and implement Equatable to the class CategoryListPage ?
https://pub.dev/packages/equatable

Here is my class declaration code:

```
class CategoryListPage extends StatefulWidget with NavigationStates {

  List<LanguageObject> _languagelistcategorydata;
  String _titleappbar;

  CategoryListPage(List<LanguageObject> languagelistcategorydata, String titleappbar) {
    _languagelistcategorydata = languagelistcategorydata;
    _titleappbar = titleappbar;
  }

  @override
  _CategoryListPageState createState() => _CategoryListPageState(_languagelistcategorydata, _titleappbar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CategoryListPage extends StatefulWidget with NavigationStates, Equatable {

  List<LanguageObject> _languagelistcategorydata;
  String _titleappbar;

  CategoryListPage(List<LanguageObject> languagelistcategorydata, String titleappbar) {
    _languagelistcategorydata = languagelistcategorydata;
    _titleappbar = titleappbar;
  }

  @override
  _CategoryListPageState createState() => _CategoryListPageState(_languagelistcategorydata, _titleappbar);
}
```

This will work. If you want to know more about `with` keyword, see [this](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins)

Comment: The class 'Equatable' can't be used as a mixin because it declares a constructor.

Comment: I found this great article, I think this might help you. https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3